# Postgres width_bucket: function width_bucket(integer, numeric[]) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, histogram

I expected results when I run a query passing an array of integers as the second argument to [`width_bucket`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-math.html) such as this:

```sql
select width_bucket(5, array[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] )
```

But if this array contains a decimal number such as this:

```sql
select width_bucket( 5, array[0, 1.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] )
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  function width_bucket(integer, numeric[]) does not exist
LINE 1: select width_bucket( 5, array[0, 1.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] )
               ^
```

My use case is I'm using [this function](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb-postgresql/blob/master/scripts-available/CDB_JenksBins.sql) to calculate my data's breaks, which won't always be integers (and I've seen used elsewhere [used with `width_bucket` in that codebase](https://github.com/CartoDB/crankshaft/blob/02a58873b2ab7d355966f80b6f189210e4356ac9/src/pg/sql/19_contour.sql#L112) so I'm not sure why it's not working here).

How can I get `width_bucket` to accept an array of non-integers?

[Edited to add link to the Postgres docs for the `width_bucket` function, which says that it accepts "anycompatiblearray" although I don't see where the list of "compatible" array types are defined.]

Comment: can you try function overload: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-overload.html

Comment: @Mark do you mean to declare different arguments types when creating the `width_bucket` function? `width_bucket` is a built-in function so I'm not creating it and thus can't define it with different parameters.

Comment: array is container type, means contain homogeneous subtype. numeric array can only contain numeric value. int array can only contain integer. Yes, create the same function name with different argument types.

Comment: I tried searching the source code for `width_bucket` but it's not defined in PSQL: https://doxygen.postgresql.org/arrayfuncs_8c.html#ab29158957fbcf04593e0b58115c45e59  So I don't see how I can run something like `CREATE FUNCTION width_bucket(APPROPRIATE ARGUMENTS HERE)`. I understand what you're saying in principle but I don't see how I can implement it. If you have any guidance that would be great.

Comment: can you get the definition of `width_bucket`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696034/how-to-get-complete-function-definition-script-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is misleading here. The issue is not that `width_bucket` does not support a numeric array, it's that it does not seem to support a mismatch of types between the operand and the thresholds values.

All of these work and return the same value:

```sql
select width_bucket( 5.0, array[0, 1.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] )
select width_bucket( 5::numeric, array[0, 1.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] )
```