# Need to find what this is doing cu_cr_

Tags: qliksense

Below is part of the SQL code I am converting into Qlik Sense data load. I am stuck as to what the

cu_cr_ is doing can anyone help me with this?

```
SELECT  a.auftrnr, a.lfdpos, a.bmnr, $1 datum,
SUM(a.stk)::INTEGER istk,
(SUM(a.stk)*c.breite*c.hoehe)/1000000 iqm,
d.bmbez,
cu_cr_anzahl_ptyp(c.aufnr, c.poskonr, c.tnrvater, 340) chambre,
c.jobnr, c.schicht,
cu_cr_dicke_ptyp(c.aufnr ,c.poskonr , c.tnrvater , 340) dicke
FROM    tt_bcydok a,  pmyplan c, pmsbm d
WHERE   a.bmnr IN ( 7101 , 7103 )
{  AND a.stk>0  }
AND   a.auftrnr = c.auftrnr
AND   a.lfdpos = c.plfdpos
AND   a.bmnr = c.bmnr
AND   a.bmnr = d.bmnr
GROUP BY a.auftrnr,a.lfdpos,a.bmnr,d.bmbez,c.poskonr,c.tnrvater,c.aufnr,
c.jobnr,c.schicht,c.breite,c.hoehe
```

Answer (score 0):

Search engines aren't finding that particular function, so it does not appear to be one that is included as a standard function or as part of a database extension. So it's likely a custom function that someone else in your organization created.

Do you have any visibility into the database you're pulling from? If it's a PostgreSQL db, you may be able to run a function like the one below to see the function definition, including its parameters and return type:

`select pg_catalog.pg_get_functiondef('cu_cr_anzahl_ptyp'::regproc::oid);`

(Credit to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48696837/11486874) for how to use the `pg_get_functiondef()` function)

Again, if using a PostgreSQL db, you can use the pgAdmin tool to see things in a more visual way, as well.

[image: Screenshot of pgAdmin functions dropdown])